# Semantic way to handle a button group

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I have a list of audio streams that is hidden or shown depending on whether a user clicks on a a div element with class 'btn-group'. My mark up is similar to twitter bootstrap's button group, like so:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Expand
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

That's fine, but it seems unfortunate that this important bit of functionality is hidden in a `div` element rather than something more meaningful. Is there an aria-role that would make sense? Is there some other approach folks would recommend?

Comment: how about using buttons instead of anchors? there's a start. you could also nest it all in unordered lists while ditching the div

Answer (score 0):

A decent solution could be to give the aria landmark role for button to the btn-group div like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="button">
```

That way, screen readers will understand the nature of the group.